# Subscript out of range error on an else statement

Tags: excel, vba

When I try to run my code I get a "subscript out of range" error when it hits the else statement in this piece of code:

```
  If Cells(i + 4 - n, 9).Value > 0 Then
        Cells(i + 4 - n, 9).Interior.ColorIndex = RGB(93, 255, 132)
        Else
        Cells(i + 4 - n, 9).Interior.ColorIndex = RGB(255, 83, 83)
  End If
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: what are `i` and `n`?

Comment: just a way for excel to know where it is, and i use these other places with no error.

Comment: yes I also checked.... `Interior.ColorIndex = RGB(93, 255, 132)` this thing is causing error

Comment: Now it works, it was the index part that was causing me problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try-

```
If Cells(i + 4 - n, 9).Value > 0 Then
        Cells(i + 4 - n, 9).Interior.Color = RGB(93, 255, 132)
        Else
        Cells(i + 4 - n, 9).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 83, 83)
  End If
```